# Текстуры с очень высоким разрешением OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

Почему текстуры с разрешением выше, чем 16к, не отображаются?
Текстуры загружаю с помощью SDL2_Image при помощи такого кода:

```
void TextureImage::LoadTextureFromFile(const std::string& path) {
    glGenTextures(1, &_textureID);
    SDL_Surface* data = IMG_Load(path.c_str());

    if (data) {
        auto nrComponents = static_cast<uint16_t>(data->format->BytesPerPixel);
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(_textureType, _textureID);

        if (_textureType == GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, data->w, data->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data->pixels);
        else if (_textureType == GL_TEXTURE_1D)
            glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, format, data->w, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data->pixels);

        glGenerateMipmap(_textureType);
        glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("Texture failed to load at path: " + path);
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(data);
}
```

Любые текстуры нормально грузит, но как только выше 16к, то она просто не отображается
Вариант с "комп не тянет" не прокатит, видеокарта GTX 980Ti, и проблема явно не в этом
Версия OpenGL 4.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А давайте подумаем, что такое текстура размером 16к? это 16384х16384. Это уже 256 мегабайт, если цвет однобайтновый. А если 4 байта, то это уже гигабайт...

я смутно представляю, зачем может понадобиться такая большая текстура. Более того, для некоторых видеокарт это уже на почти половина или четверть их памяти.

Давайте посмотрим, а как дела у других? https://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/feature/GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE и видим такое

| Value | Number of users |
| --- | --- |
| 16384 | 14599 (44%) |
| 8192 | 15182 (46%) |
| 4096 | 1547 (5%) |
| 2048 | 1807 (5%) |
| 1024 | 209 (1%) |
| -1 | 1 (0%) |

то есть, больше 16к видеокарты не поддерживают.

Что же делать, если хочется отрисовать квадрат с такой текстурой? Для начала подумать, а будет ли такой квадрат так детально виден? даже если размер экрана в 4к пикселей шириной, это по 4 точки на физический пиксель. то есть, нет смысла.

Но если очень-очень хочется? Большой квадрат можно разбить на 4 поменьше и отрисовать их, используя 4 текстуры. или 16...

Я не видел ещё в разработке, что бы одна текстура не влазила в память, другое дело, все текстуры вместе не влазят.

P.S. Придумал один случай, когда действительно может быть такая текстура - это обработка фотографий очень высокого разрешения. Ну и отрисовывается кусками на экране. Но тут лучше все равно разбивать на куски, как gogle maps.

Comment: «зачем может понадобиться такая большая текстура» — для гиперреалистичного 8к гейминга? (=

Comment: для него понадобится 8к текстура. максимум

Answer (score 3):

У OpenGL можно узнать максимальный размер текстуры, который она понимает:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
```

Comment: Ну да, записалось 16384 в переменную..А можно как-нибудь увеличить это значение?

Comment: @ГлебТруфанов увы, это максимальный размер, ограниченный либо аппаратурой, либо драйвером

Answer (score 2):

Тут стоит различать две задачи - собственно отображение текстуры высокого разрешения, и создание буфера 2d текстуры.

При создании буфера текстуры высокого разрешения имеются вполне конкретные ограничения, вытекающие из аппаратных возможностей современной техники. Для 8 битной 16к argb текстуры понадобится выделение цельного участка памяти размером в сотни мегабайт, что крайне затруднительно даже при наличии нескольких гигабайт видеопамяти. А для для попиксельного индексирования необходимо использовать два байта на индекс. Аппаратная поддержка для текстурных буферов разрешения выше 16k требует значительных вложений без явных преимуществ.

Однако ограничения размер создаваемых текстурных буферов не ограничивают размер отображаемых текстур. Например Rage от id Software еще в 2011 году использовала текстуры 128k. Это достигается за счет различных приемов поточной передачи текстур (texture streaming), когда в видеопамять транслируются только куски, нужные в данный момент: косвенное обращение через таблицу, через аппаратное отображение виртуальной памяти, через обработку запросов непосредственно от семплера.

https://silverspaceship.com/src/svt/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7AG23s2_AM